# Linux: Send mail after a process id finishes or is killed

Tags: linux, email, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I want to be notified on my email after another user's process kills or finishes.  I can identify another user's process by its process id or the name of the process appearing in "top" command.

In order to do the same I wrote the following script:

```
while true; do
  if ps -ef | grep -q 'process_name'; then
    sleep 1
  else
   echo "complete" | mail -s "process exiting" abc@gmail.com
  fi
done
```

However, I find that even after another user's process finishes or the other user kills his or her process, still I am not getting any notification or email. Can someone please help me with this a bit.

Comment: Is this really the exact code you're using? You're sending the 'complete' mail in an infinite loop, which might result in your address or host being blocked...

Comment: @mata Yes this is the code I am using

Comment: @mata Is there some way by which I may correct my code

Comment: You should probably break out of the while loop after sending the mail.

Comment: https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/bc-waitpid.pl may or may not be helpful.

Comment: does `echo "test email" | mail -s "process exiting" abc@gmail.com` work from the command line, If not you need to fix  your `mail` processing. Good luck.

Comment: try to use "watch -p -n 1 "pgrep process_name || echo "my mail" | mail -s "my info" info@foo.com

Answer (score 3):

The problem is most likely this check:

```
if ps -ef | grep -q 'process_name'; then
```

It will always be `true`. Why? Just run it directly on the command line without the `-q` to `grep` and it will be obvious:

```
$ ps -ef | grep 'process_name'
user    4550  3349  0 09:17 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --colour=auto process_name
$ echo $?
0
```

The above example shows that the `grep` will always be successful because it finds itself!

There are many ways to fix that. One way is to use [`pgrep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep) instead of `grep`.

```
if pgrep 'process_name' > /dev/null; then
```

Comment: Is there some way by which I may specify the process id instead of process name

Comment: Yes, you can do that with `kill -0` which just checks whether a pid exists. That is: `if kill -0 $pid 2> /dev/null; then`

Comment: Is there any way of matching the "command" value.  For example, in the IF statement above using string matching to equal the value "command"?

Answer (score 2):

Another common technique to prevent the `grep` process from matching itself is to surround one of the letters in the pattern with `[]`, like this:

```
grep -q '[p]rocess_name'
```

If you know the process of, then you don't need `grep` at all, you can use the exit code of `ps` itself:

```
if ps -p pid &> /dev/null; then
    sleep 1
```

where pid is of course the process id.

Comment: Wow, neat. Didn't know about this little gem.

Comment: Is there some way by which I may specify the process id instead of process name

Comment: @JannatArora in that case there's a better way than grep, using ps alone, see my updated answer