# Endless pgrep emailing me in linux -- how can I stop it?

Tags: linux, loops, email, while-loop, grep

I followed the code found at this stack overflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34709788/linux-send-mail-after-a-process-id-finishes-or-is-killed) and wrote a .sh job to run some code and then email me when it was finished.

```
while true; do
  if pgrep compile3 > /dev/null; then
    sleep 1
  else
   echo "complete" | mail -s "process exiting" EMAIL@gmail.com
  fi
done
```

I seem to have created an endless loop where it continues to email me every second that the process is complete. HELP. How do I stop it from emailing me 20 emails a minute?

I tried `pkill all`, `killall pgrep`.

I have no idea how to stop all these emails.
Thank you

Comment: That's the bad thing about computers in general -- they do exactly what you tell them to do... You should also note you `sleep 1` if the process is found, but not if it is not (you just rapid-fire email yourself as fast as the computer can). You should always consider limiting any potential run-away loop. You could, (in addition to adding the `break`) simply refactor your test to `if ! pgrep compile3 > /dev/null; then echo "complete | ..."; break; fi; sleep 1;` so that the `sleep` statement is completely outside the `if` statement.

Comment: Run `ps` (you may need to add -a or similar) to find the process that's running `sleep` and then `kill` it's parent process. You might need `kill -9` eventually to do it. wrt `wrote a ".sh" job` - shell scripts do not end in ".sh" or any other suffix so that terminology is odd and off putting, just say `wrote a shell script`. Always think long and hard before writing an infinite loop (e.g. `while true; do`) as they're rarely what you really want!

Comment: Thanks everyone, you're totally right about computers and code and thinking hard about writing infinite loops. I found that I had actually killed the program already but the queue of emails spooled up was insane. Thanks again for your help all.

Answer (score 1):

A `break` to terminate the loop will stop the loop's execution once the ideal condition has been met.

```
while true; do
  if pgrep compile3 > /dev/null; then
    sleep 1
  else
   echo "complete" | mail -s "process exiting" EMAIL@gmail.com
   break
  fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks! Super helpful. Any suggestions on how to END the loop that is now currently running though?

Comment: Is restarting your server an option? If you can't find the process number of the script that's running, or terminate it by sending a SIGINT, then restarting the server is always a quick solution.